# Renaming / Restructuring the layout of file names in a directory

Tags: python, file, directory, batch-rename, renaming

```
import os

input_path = raw_input('Input file path here : ')

os.chdir(input_path)


for f in os.listdir(input_path):
    print f
```

I have "UDIM" texture files which are enumerated as such

`1001_Base_Color.png,
1002_Base_Color.png,
1003_Base_Color.png.`

My goal is to run through each file in the directory and reposition the number at the end of the file. `name ---> Base_Color_1001.png`

Any insight is appreciated !

Thank you

Comment: Does every file have exactly four numbers followed by an underscore in the beginning? (Also, are you running Linux or Windows?)

Comment: yes, all UDIM numbers are 4 digits long.

Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split each file name by underscores and then re-join them with underscores after appending the number to the end of the tokens:

```
for f in os.listdir(input_path):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    os.rename(f, ''.join(name.partition('_')[::-1]) + ext)
```

Comment: File "./NamingTool.py", line 12
    num, *tokens = name.split('_')
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

getting a syntax error on the *

Comment: @AMist Repalce the last two lines with: `os.rename(f, ''.join(name.partition('_')[::-1]) + ext)`.

Comment: @ekhumoro Good solution that's compatible with Python 2 indeed. Thanks.

Comment: @AMist That code requires Python 3. I've now updated my answer with ekhumoro's solution, which is compatible with Python 2.